# Ajax Form Validation, JSON code

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have 3 fields in my ajax registration form. Each of them under success has:

```
success: function (j) {
    if (j.ok){
            $(validateEmail.html(j.msg)).attr("id","accept").appendTo($('#loginform') );
    } else {
            $(validateEmail.html(j.msg)).attr("id","invalid").appendTo($('#loginform') );
    }
}
```

When the field is validated and put in correctly (i.e. password which must have 8 letters HAS 8 letters, the php sends back a JSON message of j.ok = 'true'

Is there a way to under

```
 $('#register').click(function() {
 //insert code here
    });
```

to check that all of the j.ok"s are marked as true?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details ? like some example on http://jsfiddle.net would be best ?

Comment: You really shouldn't use `invalid` and `valid` as IDs, because IDs have to be unique.

Comment: @Peter +1 OP can use eg. _custom data_, such as `.attr('data-validity','invalid')` and `.attr('data-validity','accept')`.

Comment: Are you refering the valid/invalid to my attr("id","accept") and attr("id","invalid") b/c both references to my CSS of #accept and #invalid where I define color. Like

     #invalid {
          color: #C33;
          padding: 5px;
      }

Comment: My validity is checked by:
if (!$email) {
    $response = array(
      'ok' => false, 
      'msg' => "Please specify an Email");}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter said, don't use valid/invalid as ID. Maybe you want to use classes instead, or jquery's .data().

Then, maybe you can make a counter?

```
var count = 0;
...
if(j.ok) {
  stuff;
  count = count+1;
}
```

Then you check:

```
if(count == 3) {
    allvalid;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this should work, but what if everything was valid when some1 goes back and changes something and then clicks submit, wouldn't count still be 3? but ya, I guess I can alter it a bit.

Comment: For future reference, I just made a different variable and if (j.ok) { x = 1} else {x = 0}  // and for 3 fields (x, y, z) if x + y + z == 3 then it is validated. Thank you all for your help!